# Reports that demand regular review

Tags: stocks, investing

I am a long-time *long position* holder, but am moving into more aggressive trades. I am not really looking to do "day trades" but rather in a 2 day to 90 day position.

With this context in mind and the fact that I am very new to this my question is this...

Which reports should I be reviewing on a regular basis? (I believe most reports are completed by the company but also multiple reports by the Government, such as the "Job Reports" as well as any new filing the company files with the SEC such as the Annual 10K report, - (Which reports of each exactly should I be paying attention to?) The Bond Yield report today for example. How often does it come out? How often does each report come out? (Monthly, Quarterly, Annually...) Which report should I make sure that I am up early and awaiting for? Which are that important that require my constant awareness? There must be a comprehensive list or flow chart that illustrates the recommended report reading?

I'm trying to figure out exactly what I need to read in order not only to prosper in the near short-term but also maintain the best situational awareness possible.

Thank you so much for any help.